# How to assert the right value in reactjs unit test?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, unit-testing

I have written a reactjs component with an onClick event. This will change a text in the component, this is the component:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react'

export default class SimpleComponent extends Component{

constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state ={tekst:'leeg'}
}

handleClick = () =>{
        console.log('handleclick!!!');
        this.setState({tekst:'hallo'});
}

render() {
        return (
         <div>
            {this.state.tekst}
             simple comp
            <button onClick={this.handleClick} />   

         </div>
        )
      }
}
```

I wrote a unit test to test the onClick event:

```
import React from 'react';
import TestUtils from 'react-dom/test-utils';
import SimpleComponent from './SimpleComponent'
import expect from 'expect'

var renderer = TestUtils.createRenderer();

renderer.render(<SimpleComponent />);

var subject = renderer.getRenderOutput();

console.log(subject);

describe('Simple component',() => {
    it('should ...', () => {
        let btn = subject.props.children[2];
        btn.props.onClick();
        console.log('btn',btn)
        //let t = subject.props.children[0]
        //console.log('t',t)
        let tekst = subject.props.children[0]; 
        //console.log('tekst',tekst);
        expect(tekst).toEqual('hello');  // => true
    })
})
```

The test hits the handleClick event but the tekst is still the old one, it should be 'hallo'. How can I test this scenario where the state.tekst is changed by the handleClick?

Comment: What you are using enzyme or else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do yourself a favor and use [enzyme](https://github.com/airbnb/enzyme) for unit testing. It makes life much easier. You can then write something like this:

```
describe('<Foo />', () => {
  it('changes state on btn click', () => {
    const wrapper = shallow(<Foo />);
    wrapper.find('button').simulate('click');
    expect(wrapper.state().tekst).toBe('hallo');
  });
});
```

Comment: is there pros/cons between jtest anf enzymes

Comment: jtest? I think it's for java.

Comment: Enzyme is just a set of testing utilities, you use it with jest.